# using remotes::install_bitbucket to install R package from "feature/my_dev_branch"

Tags: r, git, remotes

I am trying to install an R package from Bitbucket using install_bitbucket, but I can't install a specific dev branch that is saved under "feature/my_dev_branch".

The following code works when I want to install the package from another dev branch

```
remotes::install_bitbucket(
  repo = "username/repo@another-branch", 
  auth_user = bitbucket_user, 
  password = bitbucket_pass)
```

But this doesn't

```
remotes::install_bitbucket(
  repo = "username/repo@feature/my_dev_branch", 
  auth_user = bitbucket_user, 
  password = bitbucket_pass) 

Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from Bitbucket:
```